# How to handle HTTP status code 404 in wso2 EI?

Tags: wso2, http-status-code-404, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am calling 2 sequence inside iterator. But if any of the sequence is failing with HTTP status code 404 then control is going to fault sequence and other sequences are not being executed. Is there a way i can handle this issue and my all sequences should run and iterator should be executed as there is no issue in any sequence.  I wrote custom error handler sequence to handle 404 status code.

Basically how to handle HTTP status code 404 response and ignore that 404 code. Set some custom error message and continue other sequences in the flow.

Thanks,
Vipin

Comment: Can you attach your endpoint configurations

Comment: Hi Shanaka, what endpoint configuration you are reffering to? Could you plz elaborate a bit? I am making a POST rest call.

Comment: "any of the sequence is failing with HTTP status code 404 " are you making any external endpoints in the sequences. Where do you get the HTTP status code 404?

Comment: Yes, I am calling external system,  which is returning 404 status with error message "Category does not exist". I want to handle this response code (404) as i am able to handle any other status code(200,201 etc) But seems its not possible. I need to write error sequence to handle 404 scenario. Hope I am making some sense now.

Comment: @vipin Have you solve it and know how to handle 404? I also get 'org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 404 Error: Not Found' instead of message from site :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use axis2 property HTTP_SC and the SWITCH mediator to handle the HTTP status of the response.
Here is a sample API. It has three GET resources, one /exists just returns 200, /test404 emulates call to not existent Uri, and /testnot404 - calls the /exist URI. The message processing in both methods is the same - they use switch mediator to handle HTTP_SC axis2 property.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="StakeOverflow" context="/so">  <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/exist">  <inSequence>  <respond/>    </inSequence>    </resource>    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/test404">
      <inSequence>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <http method="GET" uri-template="http://localhost:8280/so/notExist"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <switch source="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_SC')">
            <case regex="404">
               <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                  <format>{"result":"404"}</format>
                  <args/>
               </payloadFactory>
            </case>
            <default>
               <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                  <format>{"result":"not 404"}</format>
                  <args/>
               </payloadFactory>
            </default>
         </switch>
         <property name="HTTP_SC" value="200" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>    </resource>
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/testnot404">
      <inSequence>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <http method="GET" uri-template="http://localhost:8280/so/exist"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <switch source="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_SC')">
            <case regex="404">
               <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                  <format>{"result":"404"}</format>
                  <args/>
               </payloadFactory>
            </case>
            <default>
               <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                  <format>{"result":"not 404"}</format>
                  <args/>
               </payloadFactory>
            </default>
         </switch>
         <property name="HTTP_SC" value="200" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>    </resource> </api>
```

Comment: Hi Maxim, Thanks for the detailed response. I will try this solution. Just one more thing, Can i get the response message as well, if 404 is coming from an existing API with proper error message? Thanks

Comment: It doesnt work. Still get 'org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 404 Error: Not Found'. It crash before <swith>.